# Dynamic loading of html and trying to display i properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

**The idea was to enable users to click on Show More ("Читај више") and to display the full article**, but then challenge is to calculate height of the container.
So I am using display:table and display:table-row so I could avoid calculating that height. Now another issue arises and that is width, because I believe that display:table doesn't have width. So how now?

Please forgive me for posting too much css, i was lazy to remove it. But javascript is all there and you can see my effort to add divs to wrap pre an article to try to fix this issue, but no avail.

**So, once again I want only PRE tag to be with a horizontal scroll bat if needed.**

Notice that:

```
.main-style{
     max-width:800px;
...
```

solution can be in css or javascript.

```js
          var $el, $ps, $up, totalHeight;
            
            window.onload = function(){
              $("pre").wrap("<div></div>");
              $("article").wrap('<div style="overflow:auto"></div>');
            };
            
            $(".sidebar-box .button").click(function() {
            
              $p  = $(this).parent();
              $up = $p.parent();
            
              $up.css({"display":"table"});
            
              $up.children('*').css({"display":"table-row"});
            
              // fade out read-more
              $p.fadeOut();
            
              // prevent jump-down
              return false;
            });
```

```css
         body {
         font-size: 16px!important;
         }
         @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
         body {
         font-size: calc(16px + (100vw - 600px) / 600)!important;
         }
         }
         @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
         body {
         font-size: 18px!important;
         }
         }
         h1 {
         font-size: 32px!important;
         }
         @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
         h1 {
         font-size: calc(32px + 4 * (100vw - 600px) / 600)!important;
         }
         }
         @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
         h1 {
         font-size: 36px!important;
         }
         }
         h2 {
         font-size: 24px!important;
         }
         @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
         h2 {
         font-size: calc(24px + 4 * (100vw - 600px) / 600)!important;
         }
         }
         @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
         h2 {
         font-size: 28px!important;
         }
         }
         h3 {
         font-size: 18px!important;
         }
         @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
         h3 {
         font-size: calc(18px + 4 * (100vw - 600px) / 600)!important;
         }
         }
         @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
         h3 {
         font-size: 22px!important;
         }
         }
         h4 {
         font-size: 15px!important;
         }
         @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
         h4 {
         font-size: calc(15px + 4 * (100vw - 600px) / 600)!important;
         }
         }
         @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
         h4 {
         font-size: 19px!important;
         }
         }
         html, body {
         height: 100%!important;
         }
         .main-style{
         min-height: 100%;
         height: auto !important;
         height: 100%;
         max-width:800px;
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
         margin-bottom: -130px;
         /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
         }
         .sidebar-box {
         max-height: 300px;
         position: relative;
         overflow: hidden;
         }
         .sidebar-box .read-more { 
         position: absolute; 
         bottom: 0; 
         left: 0;
         width: 100%; 
         text-align: center; 
         margin: 0; padding: 30px 0; 
         /* "transparent" only works here because == rgba(0,0,0,0) */
         background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, black);
         /*
         background-image: -webkit-gradient(
         linear,
         left top,
         left bottom,
         color-stop(0, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)),
         color-stop(1, rgba(255, 0, 0, 100)));
         */
         }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="main-style">
         <article class="sidebar-box">
            <h1>„TADOConnection“ – Исправан начин да се користи „LoginPrompt := true“</h1>
            <p>
               Нисам до сада никако разумео шта "LoginPrompt := true" уопште ради.
               Али сада знам да је исправан начин да се користи следећи:
            </p>
            <pre>procedure TfrmMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  con1.Provider := 'SQLOLEDB.1';
  con1.Properties['Application Name'].Value := Application.Title;
  with TIniFile.Create(ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0)) + '\setup.ini') do
  begin
    con1.Properties['Initial Catalog'].Value := ReadString('database', 'Initial Catalog', '');
                                                     con1.Properties['Ddata Source'].Value := ReadString('database', 'Data Source', '');
    if ReadBool('database', 'Integrated Security', false ) then
    begin
      con1.Properties['Integrated Security'].Value := 'SSPI';
      con1.Properties['Persist Security Info'].Value := 'False';
      con1.LoginPrompt := False;
    end
    else
    begin
      con1.Properties['Persist Security Info'].Value := 'True';
      con1.LoginPrompt := true;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.con1Login(Sender: TObject; Username, Password: string);
begin
  con1.Properties['User ID'].Value := Username;
  con1.Properties['Password'].Value := Password;
end;
</pre>
            <p>
               Овај код чита нека обележја потребна за објекат конекције из ИНИ датотеке. Онда, на основу вредности "Integrated Security" обележја које налази у фајлу одлучује да ли ће да користи уграђену безбедност (виндовс) или сикјуел сервер безбедност. Ако користи сикјуел сервер беѕбедност онда ће ОнЛогон догађај бити позван након позива фукције Опен над конекцијом. Али мало пре тога ће корисник добити на екрану образац за уност корисничког имена и лозинке. И онда можете поставити те вредности у догађају.
            </p>
            <p>
               Важно је да се користи колекција обележја за додељивање ових вредности а не замена стрингова у стринг конекције, јер тако неће хтети да ради.
            </p>
            <p class="read-more"><a href="#" class="button">Читај више</a></p>
         </article>
         <br>  
         <div class="push"></div>
      </main>
```

Comment: in the end you want to get the width or height of a dom in jQuery ??

Comment: solution can be in css or javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try having 2 states for the container

```
.container {
    max-height: 200px; // minimised
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And

```
.conainer.active {
    max-height: auto;
}
```

And the *show more* button can just add the active class to the container.

```
document.querySelector("#showMore").addEventListener(function(){
    document.querySelector(".contaner").classList.add("active");
});
```

Where *showMore* is the id of the button and *container* is the class of the article.

Comment: Yes, that is it, simple but yet the right way to do it, thank you very much. Will try to remember this as a method and as a lesson - > simplicity is just the best!

Answer (score 0):

with

```
$('#theExactId')[0].getBoundingClientRect()
$(yourDom)[0].getBoundingClientRect()
```

you can get these attrs

bottom

height

left

right

top

width

x

y

as a number

Comment: so I don't need to calculate anything, you are saying?

Comment: just check it here on stackoverflow for example set an id to a dom on this page and use the method with ur id

Comment: I am getting 300 px, and that is the size of partially shown article, we need to get the size of a full article

Comment: Thank you Alireza, but couldn't do it with that method I was clearly getting rect of an article and it returns 300, anyway nick zoum's solution worked, so I am good, thanks again.